# Unable to load referenced library System.DirectoryServices.dll ... System Error &H8013110e&

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

All of the sudden, I'm no longer able to build a Solution without getting an error in VS 2010. A minute ago I was able to build, and now I can't.

The error is:

> Unable to load referenced library 'C:\Program Files\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.DirectoryServices.dll':
>   System Error &H8013110e&

I've checked and the .dll is there. 
I've re-booted and grabbed the latest version from Team Foundation Server.

Any ideas?

Comment: remove the refernce and re-add it.

Comment: Thanks; tried that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @mg1075 Any luck with this issue? Are you targeting the .NET 4.0 Framework?

Comment: Still in process... I ran the Cleanup Tool, and re-installed the .NET Framework 4.0, but the error remained. Also, Chkdsk ran when re-starting. At the moment, I'm in the process of re-installing VS 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-installed VS 2010, and the error no longer appears.

Comment: Odd, sucks that it came down to that, but at least you got it resolved.

Comment: Accepting this answer, not because it's a great answer, but because the problem disappeared after the re-install of VS 2010. @rsbarro's response was very informative.

Answer (score 1):

This [post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxsetup/thread/31476399-0c02-4bc3-8e34-72b5f5defd7d) indicates that this error message represents a [BadImageFormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx). That exception, combined with the steps you have already taken, makes me think that maybe your install of .NET has become corrupted. I had a similar issue a while back (while using a VM) and I had to repair the .NET Framework on my VM using the [.NET Framework Cleanup Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2008/08/28/8904493.aspx) to finally resolve the issue.

If you check the comment on the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187367/caching-application-block-crashing-iis), I posted the steps I took when using the .NET cleanup tool.